# Troubles registering custom metrics to Micrometer & Spring Boot 2

Tags: metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I'm having issues registering custom metrics to MeterRegistery.

What it looks like is that Spring manages register all its metrics (70 something) and then when the control comes back to me, I'm trying to register my own too:

```
    public MetricsAwareActiveTasksRepository(ActiveTasksRepository activeTasksRepository, MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.activeTasksRepository = activeTasksRepository;

    this.createdTaskIdsCounter = meterRegistry.counter(CustomBusinessMetrics.CREATED_TASK_IDS_COUNTER);
    this.autoStoppedTasksCounter = meterRegistry.counter(CustomBusinessMetrics.AUTO_STOPPED_TASKS_COUNTER);
}
```

Unfortunately at the point where my first metric is being registered, process hangs here in micrometer:

```
    private Meter getOrCreateMeter(@Nullable DistributionStatisticConfig config,
                               BiFunction<Id, /*Nullable Generic*/ DistributionStatisticConfig, Meter> builder,
                               Id originalId, Id mappedId, Function<Meter.Id, ? extends Meter> noopBuilder) {
    Meter m = meterMap.get(mappedId);

    if (m == null) {
        if (isClosed()) {
            return noopBuilder.apply(mappedId);
        }

        synchronized (meterMapLock) {
            m = meterMap.get(mappedId);

            if (m == null) {
                if (!accept(originalId)) {
                    //noinspection unchecked
                    return noopBuilder.apply(mappedId);
                }

                if (config != null) {
                    for (MeterFilter filter : filters) {
                        DistributionStatisticConfig filteredConfig = filter.configure(mappedId, config);
                        if (filteredConfig != null) {
                            config = filteredConfig;
                        }
                    }
                }

                m = builder.apply(mappedId, config);
                meterMap = meterMap.plus(mappedId, m);
                for (Consumer<Meter> onAdd : meterAddedListeners) {
                    onAdd.accept(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

The last line that can be tracked from debugger is where synchronized block starts. From debugger I see that the main thread becomes ZOMBIE, and nothing more happens. Lock is not being released.

Did anyone have this kind of problems? Am I doing something wrong here?

BTW Here's config also:

```
    @Bean
CloudWatchMeterRegistry cloudWatchMeterRegistry(CloudWatchConfigProperties config, AmazonCloudWatchAsync amazonCloudWatch) {
    CloudWatchMeterRegistry meterRegistry = new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM, amazonCloudWatch);
    meterRegistry.config().commonTags(commonTags());
    return meterRegistry;
}
```

As you can see I also tried to register some "custom" metrics before Spring does and it succeeds, however it does not change the situation that later this is not possible.

Also after enabling DEBUG logger, the micrometer library says nothing, the last logs before actually hanging forever are the logs from spring bean lifecycle methods, like autowiring this particular constructor that registers new metrics.

Versions are: spring-boot: 2.0.2, micrometer 1.0.4

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `CloudWatchMeterRegistry` but for InfluxDB there is no need to explicitly instantiate the registry if you use the [Global Registry](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_global_registry). Have you already tried that approach?